# before_validation method not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am   a newB in rails and I am working on a project and wanted to remove trailing and leading white spaces from username and email. So I created a method in user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

    #removes the white spaces before validating the data 


    before_validation :strip_whitespace, :only => [:name,:email]

    #data validations
    validates :email, :presence =>true,  :uniqueness => {case_sensitive: false}, :format => { :with=> /([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)/, :message => "please enter a valid e-mail" }
    validates :name, :presence=>true
    validates :password ,:presence =>true, :confirmation=> true #, :length =>{ :minimum=>6, :maximum=>30}, :format=>{:with=>/(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,30}/}

    #for the image
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

    #for the password
    has_secure_password


    #associations
    has_many :issues
    has_many :comments

end



def strip_whitespace
    self.email = self.email.squish
    self.name = self.name.squish
end
```

when I enter user information in Users.create action, the leading and trailing spaces are removed, But when I login from my sessions controller, the leading and trailing spaces are not removed and hence it shows me an error.
Please help

Code for the users controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :not_logged_in?, :only => [:new]  

  def new
    @user=User.new
  end

  def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save 
      sign_in @user
      RegistrationsMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver
        flash[:success] = 'you are successfully registered'
        redirect_to :controller => 'users' , :action => 'show', :id => @user.id
     else
        render 'new'
     end 
  end


  def show
    @user=User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      redirect_to @user
    else 
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


protected
    def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name,:email,:password,:image) 

    end

end
```

code for sessions controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

    def new


    end


    def create
        @user = User.find_by_email(params[:sessions][:email])
        if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:sessions][:password])
            sign_in @user
            redirect_to @user
        else 
            flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email or password'
            render 'new'
        end

    end



    def destroy
    end


end
```

**Please help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [When does Validation happen?](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#when-does-validation-happen-questionmark)

> The following methods trigger validations, and will save the object to the database only if the object is valid:
>
> create
>
> create!
>
> save
>
> save!
>
> update
>
> update!

When you are creating or destroying a new session, you don't actually call any of those methods on the User model so validations won't be called.

But since your database has the squished values, you need to modify your create action in the SessionsController to squish the passed in params.

```
def create
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:sessions][:email].squish)
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:sessions][:password].squish)
        sign_in @user
        redirect_to @user
    else 
        flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email or password'
        render 'new'
    end
end
```